# How to stop Auto Clicker After Enabling?

Tags: java, awtrobot

```
public class Main {
    public static boolean Clicking = true; // Clicking is false


    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        if (Clicking)
        while (true) {
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            robot.delay(1000);
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
        }
        if(mousePress(InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK == Clicking == true);
            while(true) {
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
        robot.delay(1000);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
        break;
    }
}}
```

I'm trying to make it so whenever I click ALT the Clicking stops but I'm not sure how to do it the autoclicker works perfectly fine but I'm trying to figure out a way on how to make it stop once I press a certain key

Answer (score 1):

The `Robot` class can't capture your keyboard input. And even if it could, it is blocking your program in its current state.

I've made a very simple class that illustrates what you want. How to run:

- run the program as any other from your compiler, a window will open
- click on the window and hit 'x' on your keyboard. Keep your cursor on the window. The window will change its color every time it receives a generated click from `Robot` (once a second)
- hit SPACE to stop the `Robot`

Important:
The `Timer` object contains the `Robot`. This prevents the main thread from getting blocked. The class contains a `KeyListener` object that's capable of capturing the keyboard interaction.

```
/* 
 * don't forget to add your package here
 */

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Tester extends JDialog {

    public Tester() throws AWTException {
        this.setSize( 500,  500 );               
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setSize( 500, 500 );
        panel.setBackground( Color.BLACK );
        this.add( panel );        
        this.setVisible( true );
        this.requestFocus();

        Robot robot = new Robot();
        this.addKeyListener( new KeyListener() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                    panel.setBackground( new Color( getHue(), getHue(), getHue(), 255 ) );
                    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);                            
                }
              });
            
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                if ( e.getKeyChar() == 'x' ) {
                  timer.setRepeats(true);
                  timer.start();                  
                }

                if ( e.getKeyChar() == ' ' ) {
                    timer.stop();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
              
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
            
        });
    }

    private int getHue() {
        return (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws AWTException{
        Tester tester = new Tester();
    }
}
```

What it looks like:

[image]

Comment: I tried to run it but I don't see any windows and the code ends with Process finished with exit code 0 thats it

Comment: Run it in Eclipse or IntelliJ please: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/ or https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=windows

Comment: I've added a video (gif actually) of the result in IntelliJ.